# How to fix IDA not automatically updating the graph layout?

Tags: ida

I installed IDA Free 8.3 and found that, unlike older versions, it doesn't automatically update the graph layout when I make a change. Say I have the following node:

[image]

If I add a comment, I get this:

[image]

I have to manually click "Layout graph" in the context menu to fix it:

[image]

In previous versions, this last step wasn't necessary.

Things I have tried:

- Added another comment after clicking "Layout graph," just in case there was a custom graph layout present.
- Unchecked and re-checked the options "Re-layout graph if nodes overlap" and "Re-layout graph upon screen refresh".
- Disassembled the program from scratch (to reset any settings stored inside the IDB).
- Renamed the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Hex-Rays\IDA

Has anyone else run into this? Anything else I could try? Thank you.